# Can't access USB HDD

Tags: linux, fdisk, external-hdd

I just bought a WD 1TB Caviar Blue drive, and a Bytecc HD-35SU enclosure for it.  Snapped the drive in, went to plug it in on my laptop, nothing happened.  I figured that probably meant I needed to format it, so I tried to use `fdisk`.  The new drive isn't listed.  So I looked at `dmesg`, and I see this:

```
[  119.764054] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[  120.265826] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[  120.265933] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 2329: 8020
[  120.265958] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  120.266153] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  120.266156] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[  121.306221] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access                                    PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[  121.307330] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  121.390676] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  121.391151] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 72057594037927936 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  121.391896] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  121.391901] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  121.391907] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  121.393159] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  121.394280] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  121.394290]  sdc: unknown partition table
[  121.395383] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  121.396508] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  121.396513] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

I don't particularly know what that all means, but what concerns me is this line:

```
[  121.391151] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 72057594037927936 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
```

That doesn't even make sense, right?  Could it be because it is unformatted and had no partition table?  However, I can't use `fdisk` to do any of that, because it says that it cannot read /dev/sdc...

Is my brand-new drive fried?

Comment: What type of file system are you trying to make?

Comment: Bad enclosure? The storage driver is detecting the drive's size as 32 exabytes and/or zero bytes. Things are screwed up here at a lower level than partitions.

Comment: Was the power on when you slapped the drive in?  While SATA is hot pluggable, the USB chipset might have issues with that.  Try power cycling the enclosure.

Comment: Most likely the enclosure does not support drives that large, which require the larger 16 byte scsi commands instead of the more conventional 12 byte ones.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the sort of thing you get with "real" scsi and an unterminated connection - which suggests to me that those saying that it is an issue with the enclosure are probably right. As a first step, though, just check that all the cords and cables are properly plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Either the disk's controller is broken or your kernel configuration. Try plugging it to a different computer to determine which is the case.

*(Side note: `72057594037927936 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)` is a garbage, but actually partially right: if you issue `echo $[ 72057594037927936 * 512 ]`, you'll get `0` because of integer wrap. The absurd number probably comes from some default value setting.)*

Answer (score 0):

Bytecc support site indicates that the enclosure is for WinXP and up only. 
A/O 31Jul2017 I can find no drivers to use this enclosure with Linux (or any other OS, for that matter.)

Answer (score -1):

Usually it is unformatted.

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
```

n - new partition
Are you able to access it?

Comment: This is not a partitioning issue.